# Do I need a JAR file to run a Flink application?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am working through the book `Stream Processing with Apache Flink` by Fabian Hueske and Vasiliki Kalavri.

The book includes an example Flink application and I want to figure out how to run the file. It is a scala file located [here](https://github.com/streaming-with-flink/examples-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/github/streamingwithflink/chapter1/AverageSensorReadings.scala) in their github repo.

Must I turn it into a JAR file before I run it? If so, how do I convert the file to JAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for SQL queries submitted with Flink‘s SQL client, a user needs to package a JAR file. Usually, a Flink program file can be packaged using a Maven or Gradle project:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/project-configuration/#maven-quickstart

Comment: Maven is a tool for converting java files into JAR files, amongst other uses. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, is it fair to say that I can write my Flink files in either Java _or_ Scala?

Comment: Yes, Maven is responsible for dependency management and artifact building. Java or Scala are supported.